# Почему при нажатии на кнопку поиска страница обновляется

Tags: html, css

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
form {
  position: relative;
  width: 750;
  margin: 25px;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #F9F0DA;
  color: #9E9C9C;
}
button {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F9F0DA;
}
```

```html
<form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>
```

Comment: А почему она не должна обновляться?

Comment: то типо поисковая строка

Comment: И что? Ты форму написал? Написал. Кнопку САБМИТА ФОРМЫ в неё вставил? Вставил. Теперь ещё раз вопрос: почему при сабмите формы страница не должна обновляться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button type="submit"` - означает, что при клике на неё все данные из формы будут отправлены на сервер. Отсылается запрос всегда по тому адресу, который указан в атрибуте `action`. Если такой атрибут отсутствует или он пустой `action=''`, то форма будет отправляться на тот же url, на котором находится.  Поэтому происходит просто обновление страницы

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться.

Comment: ..... Что "это"?

Comment: А не подскажеш что надо писать в action="" чтобы поиск работал?

Comment: Относительный путь к скрипту php. Типа "search.php" Или "/product/search/"